# Partial derivative in terms of Kronecker delta and the Laplacian operator

Tags: real-analysis, dirac-operator, real-algebra

How can the following term:

$$ T_{ij} = \partial_i \partial_j \phi$$

be written in terms of Kronecker delta and the Laplacian operator $\mathbin\bigtriangleup = \nabla^2$?

I mean is there a relation:

$$ T_{ij} = \partial_i \partial_j \phi = ~?? ~ \delta_{ij} \mathbin\bigtriangleup \phi  $$

But what are ?? terms.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the operator $\partial_i\partial_j$ cannot be expressed in terms of the Laplacian $\nabla^2$.

Indeed, take any real $a$ and $b$. If $\phi(x_1,\dots,x_n)=ax_1x_2+b(x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2)/(2n)$ for all real $x_1,\dots,x_n$, then $\nabla^2\phi=b$ everywhere, whereas $\partial_1\partial_2\phi=a$. So, the knowledge of the value of $\nabla^2\phi$ can in general tell us nothing about the value of $\partial_1\partial_2\phi$. That is, $\partial_1\partial_2\phi$ is not any function of $\nabla^2\phi$.